# How to make end time of 1st row as start time of 2nd row in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How can I make end time of 1st row as start time of 2nd row (I intend to add some value in seconds to the start time in every row and the end time of the very same row needs to be start time of next row).

For example,

```
start-time|time_to_add|endtime

10:00:00  |30 secs   |10:00:30

10:00:30  | 15 secs  | 10:00:45

10:00:45  | 10 secs  | 10:00:55
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

*edit*

```
starttime  | val_to_add |  endtime

10:30:00   | 30     |   10:30:00 + 0:0:30

10:30:00 + 0:0:30  | 30   | 10:30:00 + 0:0:30 + 0:0:30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example of how to do it if `time_to_add` is a list of values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
initial_start_time = pd.to_timedelta('10:00:00')
time_to_add = ['0:00:30', '0:00:15', '0:00:15', '0:00:30', '0:00:20']
time_to_add = [pd.to_timedelta(x) for x in time_to_add]

df['time_to_add'] = time_to_add
df['end_time'] = [initial_start_time + x for x in np.cumsum(time_to_add)]
df['start_time'] = [initial_start_time] + list(df['end_time'][:-1])

df = df[['start_time', 'time_to_add', 'end_time']]
```

The column `time_to_add` is just your intervals. The column `end_time` adds the intervals times to the initial start time and the columnn `start_time` takes the end times and shifts them by one row.
The last line is just for reordering the columns.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['start-time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['start-time'])
df['time_to_add']=pd.to_timedelta(df['time_to_add'].replace(' sec', '', regex=True), unit='s')
df['end-time'] = df['start-time'] + df['time_to_add']
```

Comment: Appreciated, but I need the end-time of 1st row to become start-time of 2nd row. This code is not helping me with that

Comment: @PritamPatnaik - Not understand, can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: The example I have posted is bit confusing. If I can explain it in plain language, let's assume that we just have single row, in there I add a value, the outcome needs to be in 2nd row

Comment: @PritamPatnaik - yes, it is reason for create `mcve`. Or need `df['end-time'] = df['start-time'].shift(-1)`  ?

Comment: kindly refer the edit done to the post. Thanks for being patient :)

Comment: @PritamPatnaik - I dont understand, what are input data and expected output? Only first row? Or first row and column `time_to_add` ? Or soemthing else?